# SELECT from One-to-many relationship

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, fastapi

I'm trying to get a user's first name and last name, as well as all bank accounts associated with that user. This is what I'm getting:

```json
[
    {
        "FirstName": "X",
        "LastName": "Y",
        "RIB": "ABC123456789"
    },
    {
        "FirstName": "X",
        "LastName": "Y",
        "RIB": "BZE123456789"
    },
    {
        "FirstName": "X",
        "LastName": "Y",
        "RIB": "DFG123456789"
    }
]
```

Where RIB is the user's bank account. While I was expecting it to return the first and last names once, then a list of all users' bank accounts instead of repeating the user full names...

```py
db.query(
    Users.FirstName,
    Users.LastName,
    models.UserLocalBankAccounts.RIB,
).join(models.UserLocalBankAccounts).filter(Users.UserId == 1).all()
```

Comment: _"While I was expecting it to return the first and last names once, then a list of all users' bank accounts instead of repeating the user full names..."_ - SQL doesn't do that. So either **(1.)** use the first & last names from just the first record, and then RIBs from all records. **(2.)** Or, select only RIB's to get just those for the UserID and then separately select first & last name for that UserID. I prefer option 1 since it's fewer queries to the DB. You can then use [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) on the result.

Comment: If you have a [relationship](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/basic_relationships.html) between your `User` and `UserLocalBankAccounts`, then you should just be able to query your `User` model, and the list of bank accounts will be fetched automatically.

Comment: @M.O. won't container_eager or joinedload be necessary in this case.?

Comment: @Siqueler I would probably add it just to avoid an extra database roundtrip, but it's not necessary, especially if OP intends on using it with a pydantic `response_model` in FastAPI (which I'm guessing from the tags). In that case, pydantic's `from_orm` will make sure the relationship is loaded (lazily).